# How to unescape url that have unicode characters

Tags: javascript, url, unicode, escaping

I have url like this: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzeum_Dawnej_Wsi_%E2%80%9EDomek_Tkaczki%E2%80%9D in browser address bar it show up as Muzeum_Dawnej_Wsi_„Domek_Tkaczki” but when I copy it to clipboard it show encoded, how can I unescape the url like this? I've tried to use this:

```
unescape(location.href);
```

but got url that look like this:

```
https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzeum_Dawnej_Wsi_âDomek_Tkaczkiâ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unescape` is incomplete and deprecated:

> Note: Do not use `unescape` to decode URIs, use `decodeURI` instead.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

The latter works as expected:

```js
console.log(decodeURI('https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzeum_Dawnej_Wsi_%E2%80%9EDomek_Tkaczki%E2%80%9D'));
```